# Configure S3 | Gaufrette | Sylius?

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sylius, gaufrette

I want to integrate AWS S3 into Sylius. What is the correct way to configure it? In dnd you will find the configuration file of Sylius and Gaufrette inside the package?

Answer (score 3):

Start by configuring your bundles:

Some gist here
https://gist.github.com/ylastapis/e392ac72543504b05b8a332a935e8b9c

Then you'll have to define some services:

```
services:
    sylius.image_uploader:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\ImageUploader
        arguments: [ "@app.sylius.image_uploader.config" ]
    app.sylius.image_uploader.config:
        class: 'Gaufrette\Filesystem'
        factory: [ "@knp_gaufrette.filesystem_map", get ]
        arguments: [ 'sylius_image' ]
```

If you add a new filesystem to gaufrette, don't forget to update conf

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        sylius_image:
            aws_s3:
                service_id: app.amazon_s3
                bucket_name:  "%amazon_s3.bucket_name%"
                options:
                    directory: '%amazon_s3_folder_pictures%'
    filesystems:
        sylius_image:
            adapter: sylius_image
```